# Default values are incorrect in html angular application

Tags: html, angularjs

In this angularjs application I have a login page initially where the user types Username and Password.  Once in the application, they can chose another page that requires a different username and password for database access.  I want the database username to default to a different value than the login and the password to be blank with a placeholder of `Enter a password`.  However, the defaults in the database page are using the initial login values.
This is the html of the login page:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="width: 80%" autofocus ng-model="credentials.username" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="width: 80%" ng-model="credentials.password" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is the html of the database login:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                            <label id="inputDBUserNameLabel" style="margin-left: 10px;" >User Name: </label>
                            <input id="inputDBUserNameText" type="text" ng-model="inputUserName" class="form-control demoInput" value="test" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 25%;"/>
                        </div>
                         <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                            <label id="inputDBPasswordLabel" style="margin-left: 10px;" >Password: </label>
                            <input id="inputDBPasswordText" type="password" ng-model="inputPassword" class="form-control demoInput" placeholder="Enter a password" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 25%;"/>
                        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Below is the code to my controller when connecting to the the database.
When entering the correct username and password it works:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('vow-administration-ui')
  .controller('UpgradeCtrl', ['$scope', 'UpgradeDB',
      function($scope, upgradeDB) { 
        $scope.title = "Upgrade Database";

        $scope.inputServerName = '';
        $scope.inputDatabaseName = '';
        $scope.inputUserName = '';
        $scope.inputPassword = '';

        $scope.outputServerName = '';
        $scope.outputDatabaseName = '';
        $scope.outputUserName = '';
        $scope.outputPassword = '';

        $scope.UpgradeDatabase = function(){

        upgradeDB.save({
          inputServerName: $scope.inputServerName,
          inputDatabaseName: $scope.inputDatabaseName,
          inputUserName: $scope.inputUserName,
          inputPassword: $scope.inputPassword,

          outputServerName: $scope.outputServerName,
          outputDatabaseName: $scope.outputDatabaseName,
          outputUserName: $scope.outputUserName,
          outputPassword: $scope.outputPassword

        }).$promise.then(function(response) {
            var responseText = response;
            console.log(responseText);
        });                
      };

  }]);
```

**UPDATE**
I removed the `ng-model=inputUserName` and both the UserName and Password fields were changed to the expected values.  That is the UserName field had the default of `test` and the Password field had the placeholder of `Enter a password` even though I did NOT remove the `ng-model` attribute from the password field.

**UPDATE**
Login Controller:

```
angular.module('vow-administration-ui')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService) {

    $scope.isProcessing = false;

    $scope.credentials = {
      domain: '',
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };



$scope.login = function() {
      AuthService.authenticateAdministrator($scope.credentials).then(function() {
          $scope.errorMessage = '';
          $scope.errorState = false;
          $location.path('/launch').replace();
        },
        function(error) {
          AuthService.destroyToken();
          $scope.errorMessage = 'Failed to authorize. ' + error.data.ExceptionMessage;
          $scope.errorState = true;
        });
    };

  });
```

Comment: Something must be happening in your controller (imo). Can we see it?

Comment: I added the controller for the database log in.

Comment: hmm.. seems fine to me. Can you do a jsbin or plunkr? I am not sure why inputUserName would have the same value as credentials.username. Maybe I am misunderstanding your question? I think a  jsbin or plunkr would help clarify the issue.

Comment: You understand the question correctly.  I don't understand why the username and password should be retained either.  I don't know what jsbin or plunkr are.

Comment: I added an update to my question.  When removing the `ng-model` of the UserName the problem is corrected even though the password field did not have the attribute removed.  So why is the `ng-model` attribute wrong?

Comment: ok.. let me look again.. last thing, and just to confirm... are you using different controllers for each view, and if so can I see the controller for the login view?

Comment: Yes. They are different views.  I have the login view in the original test. I added the login controller above...

Comment: I am sorry, I am not seeing it. (I also don't see how the user opens the database page from the login controller). If noone takes this up over the next couple hours, I will come back and start a chat. I have to go for now.

Comment: I added the login functions above.  The user logs in and from a menu selects a page in which they can enter the database log in credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the problem...
It is Google Chrome that was the problem.
Apparently, when you use ids that are a form of 'username' and 'password' Chrome tries to 'help' by inserting the previous text that was used as a username and password.

To fix the problem, I changed my ng-model names to variations of UsrNm and Pwd.

It works now.

Comment: so it was looking at the ng-model  for instances of password and not the element id and element name? good find.

Comment: Apparently this is the case when using the browser Chrome